# How do I make the dropdown fade in and out transition?

Tags: html, css

I want to make the dropdown menu fade in/out slightly. I tried to add opacity and hover, but I could not figure it out.

```
nav ul li:hover > .midbox {
    opacity:1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

I than set `opacity:0` on `.midbox` with the same transition applied.
Below is a fiddle with an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/skf5v0Lw/

Am I supposed to use the other element hover state to affect the state of the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS transition does not work on `display` property. Use `visibility` instead. Also it should be set on the dropdown UL rather than the inner element.

```
/* Hide Dropdowns by Default
 * and giving it a position of absolute */
nav ul ul {
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute; 
    width: 800px;
    top: 60px;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

/* Display Dropdowns on Hover */
nav ul li:hover > ul {
    /* display:block; */
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/skf5v0Lw/5/

Comment: If you hover over the space under the nav bar, the dropdown appears. It should only appear when you hover over the "Products" link. Is there a reason for this bug?

Comment: @okok does the *bug* also occur on your original demo? and I'm not sure what you were referring to.

Comment: This does not happen in my demo. To see what I am talking about, Hover over "Items". The dropdown will appear. Afterwards with the cursor, go below the dropdown to the dark background. Then with the cursor on the dark background, try to move your cursor back up--you will see that the dropdown reappears when it shouldn't. It should only appear when you hover over links. Let me know if you see what I am referring to.

Comment: ---- Maybe this is happening because I am scrolling off the dropdown and back too quickly and the fade has not completed. Not a big issue in that case. Thanks

Comment: @okok yes, I totally agree with that, you can lower the duration time if that makes it better.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but you could check out dropotron, it allows for a bunch of settings like fade in dropdown, hover delay, and that sort of thing.

https://github.com/n33/jquery.dropotron